# Запуск nightmare js на jelastic

Tags: node.js, jelastic, nightmare.js

Сделал небольшое приложение которое раз в минуту должно производить действия на сайте и записывать результат в БД. На локальной машине все работает без ошибок, но после того как выгрузил приложение на Jelastic, после запуска все зависает на строке открытия странницы:

```
await this.nightmare
            .goto("https://google.ru")
```

Через ssh проверил что доступ к сайту из окружения есть.

```
nodejs@node /home/jelastic $ curl -LI google.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Location: http://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=0bEwWtmVFYW8zAXtg77wDA
Content-Length: 268
Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2017 04:51:29 GMT

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2017 04:51:29 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2017-12-13-04; expires=Fri, 12-Jan-2018 04:51:29 GMT; 
path=/;                                                             
domain=.google.ru
Set-Cookie: NID=119=P0j48s9F-9vk9vm8EBCmwmhwOI1cPq-u2bn7KAHZlEnzzda4hywYw-NLJqj5                                                            
K26i53qyvh3sVmsJ8vdLLjsInQatnCoFrt4k-nV-o-HtsQtxwhOX6Ck_245pUUixxCIX; expires=Th                                                            u, 14-Jun-2018 04:51:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.ru; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Кто нибудь вообще пробовал запускать такого рода приложения на jelastic или это нельзя сделать из за неких ограничений окружения?

## UPDATE

Решением является установка `Xvfb`

Comment: nightmare.js это оболочка над fantomjs. На старых версиях fantomjs нужен был X Server - это визуальная оконная система. Может из-за этого.

Comment: http://phantomjs.org/faq.html
A: In PhantomJS 1.4 or earlier, X server is still needed. The workaround is to use Xvfb. Starting with PhantomJS 1.5, it is pure headless and there is no need to run X11/Xvfb anymore.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить чистый fantom js с загрузкой страницы и по выдаваемым ошибкам найдите проблему.

Comment: @tcpack4 Действительно на сервере не стоит X server. Спасибо за подсказку.